# Heights of QPushButton and QLineEdit differ under OS-X

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I want to place a QPushButton and a QLineEdit in together one QTreeView cell by putting them in a container widget that has a QHBoxLayout. However, it doesn't look good, the button is taller than the line editor as you can see in my screen shot below. When the cell contains only a single button or editor, it fills the complete cell, which is what I want.

[image: screen shot]

The problem only occurs on OS-X (I'm using 10.6.8), under Windows and Linux it looks as expected.

I've already set the layout's contentsMargin and spacing to 0. Also setting the widget's padding and margin to 0 using style sheets didn't help. How can I fix this?

My example is in PyQt but I also added the Qt and PySide tags because I don't think it's a Python issue.

```
import sys
if True:
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
else:
    from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
    from PySide.QtCore import Qt

def setSizePolicies(widget, 
        horPolicy=QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, 
        verPolicy=QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding):
    sizePolicy = widget.sizePolicy()
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalPolicy(horPolicy)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalPolicy(verPolicy)
    widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

def createContainer():
    container = QtGui.QFrame()

    if False: # setting this to True doesn't help
        container.setStyleSheet("""
            QWidget {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                border: 1px solid blue;
                border-radius: 0px;
                background-color: #CCCCCC;
            }
            QLineEdit { background-color: #FFFF00; }        
            QPushButton { background-color: #FF00FF; } 
            QPushButton:pressed { background-color: #AA00AA; }        
        """)
    hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    hLayout.setSpacing(0)
    hLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    container.setLayout(hLayout)
    return container, hLayout

class MyTableView(QtGui.QTreeView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTableView, self).__init__()

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(3, 2)
        self.setModel(model)
        self.header().resizeSection(0, 200)
        self.header().resizeSection(1, 300)
        self.resize(550, 400)
        self.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        # Create a single QLineEdit inside a container widgets that has a 
        # QHBoxLayout. The edior fills the entire table cell.
        container0, hlayout0 = createContainer()
        lineEdit0 = QtGui.QLineEdit("Fills entire cell")
        setSizePolicies(lineEdit0)
        hlayout0.addWidget(lineEdit0)
        model.setData(model.index(0, 0), "Only a line editor")
        self.setIndexWidget(model.index(0, 1), container0)

        # Create a single QPushButton inside a container widgets that has a 
        # QHBoxLayout. The button fills the entire table cell.
        container1, hlayout1 = createContainer()
        button1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Fills entire cell")
        setSizePolicies(button1)
        hlayout1.addWidget(button1)
        model.setData(model.index(1, 0), "Only a push button")
        self.setIndexWidget(model.index(1, 1), container1)

        # When a button and editor are both put in a cell, the button is taller.
        # Also there is some overlap between them.
        container2, hLayout2 = createContainer()
        button2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Taller button")
        setSizePolicies(button2)
        hLayout2.addWidget(button2)
        lineEdit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit("Smaller editor")
        setSizePolicies(lineEdit2)
        hLayout2.addWidget(lineEdit2)
        model.setData(model.index(2, 0), "A button and an editor")
        self.setIndexWidget(model.index(2, 1), container2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tableView = MyTableView()
    tableView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is a Qt bug, and, unfortunately, I'm unaware of a workaround. The buttons in layouts are broken for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround that works for me. When using a `QToolButton` instead of a `QPushbutton` the button has the same height as the line editor.